# Can't arm ESC using arduino.(Radient Reaektor ESC)

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

My problem is simple. Cant seem to figure out how to arm my ESC using ardiuno. The circuit is installed correctly and everything is fine too. the ESC does power 3 servos that I attached and arduino controls those servos just fine. The only thing I need to know is to arm ESC. I know all ESC require a specific configuration but I cant seem to figure out what I need to do for mine. I did notice that the ESC needs a servo signal of "27" to turn its led on. Im guessing it means its ready to roll but then I send "90" and nothing happens. When I run the example servo sweep code with ESC ,the motor runs for a split second and stops. I tried to send all signals from 27 to 180 manually. nothing happens.

This is my ESC and motor: http://radientrc.com/Reaktor/

It came with the car. It isn't an upgrade or anything. The car works fine with the radio receiver . but I just can't arm the ESC to make it go lol

Hope someone can shed some light on this matter. Hopefully someone who dealt with the above menntioned ESC.

Thanks!